# Implement Kerberos authentication in java

Tags: java, kerberos, spnego

Our client have a tomcat application deployed in linux machine, and the application will call web services which is outside of their network. Till now it is working fine. But now, customer has installed Kerberos in his server. Now, we need to implement the Kerberos authentication in our java code. For testing, we have given the below standalone java program to execute in their environment.

```
public class testauthproxy {

/**
 * Uses HttpClient 4.3.4 and CommonsIO 2.4
 */

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,
        IOException {           
        testProxyAuthentication("URL");
}

public static void testProxyAuthentication(String url) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {      
    boolean skipPortAtKerberosDatabaseLookup = true;
    try {
        File loginConfig = createLoginConf();

        System.out.println("Created config '" + loginConfig.getAbsolutePath() + "':");
        System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(new FileReader(loginConfig)));

        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", loginConfig.toURI().toString());
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "/etc/krb5.conf");
        System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
        System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly",
                "false");

                Registry<AuthSchemeProvider> authSchemeRegistry = RegistryBuilder
                .<AuthSchemeProvider> create()
                .register(AuthSchemes.SPNEGO,
                        new SPNegoSchemeFactory(
                                skipPortAtKerberosDatabaseLookup)).build();

        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultAuthSchemeRegistry(authSchemeRegistry).build();
        HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
        BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

        // This may seem odd, but specifying 'null' as principal tells java
        // to use the logged in user's credentials
        Credentials useJaasCreds = new Credentials() {

            public String getPassword() {
                return null;
            }

            public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
                return null;
            }

        };
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(null, -1, null),
                useJaasCreds);
        context.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget, context);
        String responseString = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity()
                .getContent());

        System.out.println("HTTP Response: Success");
        System.out.println(responseString);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error Occurred: "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();            
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error Occurred: "+e.getMessage());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error Occurred: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * Creates a temporary krb5.conf [libdefaults] default_realm = <domain>
 * 
 * [realms] snb.ch = { kdc = <kdc> admin_server = <kdc> }
 */
private static File createLoginConf()
        throws IOException {
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("login", ".conf");
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    lines.add("com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate {");     
    lines.add("\t\tcom.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required useTicketCache=true;");        
    lines.add("\t};");

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(tempFile);
    IOUtils.writeLines(lines, "\n", writer);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(writer);
    return tempFile;
}
}
```

But we got the connection timed out error. The krb5.conf file path was correct, but for login.conf, i have created a temp file and assigned it in runtime.

I have searched in internet but couldn't get any solution. Can you please suggest if there is any other alternative solution for this?

Comment: Either you messed up the JAAS config -- not the expected subject name, syntax error, etc. -- or you messed up the Kerberos config / don't have the DNS pre-requisites / don't have the NTP prerequisites, or you simply don't have valid credentials. Enable the JAAS & Kerberos & SPNego debug traces with `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Dsun.security.spnego.debug=true -Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext` and have fun...

Comment: Now, if are really unlucky, you may have two non-compatible network appliances that aggregate/route/deaggregate TCP packets... with some side effects, i.e. the Kerberos ticket in the HTTP header gets corrupted and ethernet traffic is dropped and the SPNego fails silently on time-out. I've seen it happen. But that would be cosmic bad luck.

Answer (score 0):

> Our client have a tomcat application deployed in linux machine, and
>   the application will call web services which is outside of their
>   network. Till now it is working fine. But now, customer has installed
>   Kerberos in his server. Now, we need to implement the Kerberos
>   authentication in our java code. For testing, we have given the below
>   standalone java program to execute in their environment.

From this I understand that your client is on a separate domain than your application.

Kerberos across different domains [requires some more hoops](https://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/feature/Logging-on-to-Windows-using-Kerberos-Multiple-domain-environment).

In a nutshell, both domains must be connected to a parent domain and the parent domain would be the one issuing the tickets. The subdomains give the client a referral ticket that can be used to get a ticket from the parent domain, but the parent domain must be set-up to issue the Kerberos tickets.